# Why does the order of :set bg=dark and :set bg=light matter?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

While trying to match up my terminal's colour palette and GVim's I noticed this:

1. When I open GVim and Vim, I see:
   [image]
   (That's the same file, my `vimrc`.)
2. If I do `:set t_Co=256`, nothing happens in GVim (except it blinks), whereas the colours in the terminal now look different. If I do `:set bg=dark` now, it makes no difference (again GVim blinks).
   If I then do `:set bg=light` and then `:set bg=dark` again, I get:
   [image]

Both `:set bg=dark` and `:set t_Co=256` are present in my [vimrc](https://github.com/murukeshm/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc). Why aren't my `:set bg` and `:set t_Co` sticking, and why does setting `:set bg=dark` again after `:set bg=light` make a difference where it originally didn't?

I'm using Arch Linux, the terminal is GNOME Terminal, and I don't have a `.gvimrc`.

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb  4 2015 08:03:11)
Included patches: 1-617
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc  -L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m -lpython3.4m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm  -lruby -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The elflord colorscheme does `set background=dark`. Since it is sourced *after* your `set bg=light` it will override it.
2. `set t_Co=256` is *pointless*. It doesn't do anything in GVim and you should set your terminal emulator up properly instead.

   Also, elflord only uses basic ANSI colors in color terminals so it doesn't really matter if you force Vim to see 256 colors or if you set your `TERM` to a 256colors value; your colorscheme won't use that extended palette anyway. What happens instead is that your original `TERM` is probably `xterm` or `screen` or some other value that restricts Vim to 8 colors. But Elflord uses both "dark" and "light" colors which need a `TERM` above 8. So, forcing 256 colors will alter your colors.
3. Recommendations:

   - Don't change the value of `'t_Co'`.
   - Don't `set background`.

Comment: If elflord sets `bg` to `dark`, why does its appearance change if I set it to `light` and back again? Note that my vimrc does not do `set bg=light`.

Comment: `set bg` changes the colors and attributes of some highlight groups so that they work better on dark or light background. It is mostly arbitrary and may or may not have an effect depending on the colorscheme you use. Messing with that option is not a good idea.

Comment: I followed your advice on `bg` and `t_Co`. I'm just wondering why elflord's `set bg=dark` and mine cause such differing (yet repeatable) results?

Comment: It's the order in which they are applied. Because one is not the exact opposite of the other switching multiple times between "dark" and "light" is not a toggle between two definite and stable states.