# Togglebg from solarized changes to incorrect colorscheme

Tags: colorscheme, plugin-solarized

I've installed solarized with the bundled togglebg.vim plugin.

In my vimrc I set `background` to `light` and `colorscheme` to `solarized`, so I have light background and matching font colors from solarized-light.

When I change `background` to `dark` in my vimrc and restart vim, it starts with dark background and matching colors from solarized-dark - as advertised.

But when I use togglebg, it changes background to dark (but not dark like in solarized, almost black) and to some different colorscheme. Manual `:colorscheme solarized` doesn't fix the problem. After running togglebg double it doesn't go back to first state, but to solarized-light scheme with the same almost black background.

I have only solarized with togglebg, ctrlP and Powerline installed.

Vim running in iTerm on OS X 10.8.5

Here's my full .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()                                                                                          

syntax enable                                                                                                      
set background=light                                                                                               
colorscheme solarized                                                                                              
set t_Co=256                                                                                                       
let g:solarized_termcolors=256                                                                                     

let g:Powerline_symbols='fancy'                                                                                    

set encoding=utf-8                                                                                                 
filetype plugin indent on                                                                                          

set nocompatible                                                                                                   
set modelines=0                                                                                                    

set tabstop=2                                                                                                      
set shiftwidth=2                                                                                                   
set softtabstop=2                                                                                                  
set expandtab                                                                                                      

set ruler                                                                                                          
set relativenumber                                                                                                 

set laststatus=2                                                                                                   

set ignorecase                                                                                                     
set smartcase                                                                                                      
set gdefault                                                                                                       

inoremap jk <Esc>                                                                                                  
call togglebg#map("<F5>")
```

Comment: I can confirm that the `togglebg` doesn't work very well in `xterm` (although it works fine for me in gVim)...

Comment: Possibly related: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/why-does-the-order-of-set-bg-dark-and-set-bg-light-matter#comment1157_1891

Comment: what exactly is  togglebg?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to toggle background, add this to your `vimrc`, (edit mapping according to what you like)

I use this on OS X 10.10.2 on `iTerm`

```
function! BgToggleSol()
  if &background == "light"
    execute ":set background=dark"
  else
    execute ":set background=light"
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>ct :call BgToggleSol()<cr>
```

Check out [git](http://github.com/bk2dcradle/Dotfiles) for more.

Tip: Since you are using a mac, pasting using Command+V must be a pain. Add this to your vimrc as well

```
if &term =~ "xterm.*"
    let &t_ti = &t_ti . "\e[?2004h"
    let &t_te = "\e[?2004l" . &t_te
    function XTermPasteBegin(ret)
        set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
        set paste
        return a:ret
    endfunction
    map <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("i")
    imap <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("")
    cmap <Esc>[200~ <nop>
    cmap <Esc>[201~ <nop>
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

First `colorscheme solarized`  must be after `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`, and that may work.

If not. You should set **xterm-256** color in preferences.

Bellow you can see the settings that works for me nicely. I don't use a keymap for toggle background, instead just use `:set bg=light` or `:set bg=dark`

```
" Pathogen plugins 
execute pathogen#infect()

filetype on
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on

" Enable syntax colors
syntax enable

" Background color from color  scheme
set background=dark
" set background=light

" Solarized scheme color preferences
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
let g:solarized_termtrans = 1
let g:solarized_degrade = 0
let g:solarized_bold = 1
let g:solarized_underline = 1
let g:solarized_italic = 1
let g:solarized_contrast = "normal"
let g:solarized_visibility= "normal"
colorscheme solarized
```