# What does :set background=dark do?

Tags: colorscheme

I didn't put `color xxx` in my `.vimrc`. So I see this when I first open my `.vimrc`.

`:color` gives me `default` here.
[image: Before anything]

Then I type `:color darcula`. And it changes to this.

`:color` gives me `darcula` here (naturally).
[image: Change colorscheme]

Then I type `:set background=dark`. And it changes to this.

`:color` gives me `default` here (amazingly).
[image: Change background]

So my question is, what exactly does `:set background=dark` do?

I tried `:h background` and didn't find anything helpful. I understand that this command doesn't actually change the background, only vim will change colors accordingly. But I still want to ask this question. Because I'm really happy with the color after `:color darcula` and `:set background=dark` so I wonder how to write my own color scheme without having to put `set background=dark` in my `.vimrc`.

I took advice from @statox and put `set background=dark` at the last line of my `darcula.vim`. Then `color darcula` gives me the third screenshot. However when I put it at the first line, `color darcula` gives me the second screenshot. Also `set bg=dark` changes it to the third screenshot.

I assumed by putting it at the first line, I'm telling vim that this colorscheme is designed for a dark background. By putting it at the last line, on the contrast, I let vim assume that this colorscheme is designed for a light background and then make vim change some of it by itself (when it processes the last line).

If what I assume happened is true, my question is still unanswered. What exactly did vim change, when I use `set bg=dark` AFTER it has loaded a light colorscheme?

My entire vim configuration is available at https://github.com/MichaelMa2014/.vim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of :set bg=dark and :set bg=light matter?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/why-does-the-order-of-set-bg-dark-and-set-bg-light-matter)

Comment: @muru Greetings! I had read this question before asking mine. It is mentioned in that post that `:set bg=light` and `:set bg=dark` are not opposite, but what exactly they are is not explained. Also that post is why I want to avoid `:set background=dark` in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: interestingly I had to set this in Manjaro (Arch) after updating to "vim-runtime-8.2.0100-1" today, because suddenly the syntax changed after the update

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### What happens when you `:set background`

The basic mechanism by which `:set background` works is actually pretty simple, and
it is documented (although not particularly clearly) in `:help 'background'`.

> When 'background' is set Vim will adjust the default color groups for
> the new value.  But the colors used for syntax highlighting will not
> change.                   *g:colors_name*
> When a color scheme is loaded (the "g:colors_name" variable is set)
> setting 'background' will cause the color scheme to be reloaded.  If
> the color scheme adjusts to the value of 'background' this will work.
> However, if the color scheme sets 'background' itself the effect may
> be undone.

So what actually happens when the `'background'` option is changed is this:

#### If no colour scheme is currently loaded

Vim reloads the default colours, using foreground colours deemed appropriate for
the new setting of `'background'`

#### If a colour scheme is currently loaded

Vim reloads the colour scheme. When the colour scheme is loaded, either the
colour scheme sets colours appropriate to the new setting of `'background'`, or
the colour scheme *resets* `'background'` to the old value.

As you have already described, the `'background'` option is not intended to *set*
the background, but instead to *inform* Vim whether the background is dark or
light.

So if the colour scheme resets `'background'`, Vim takes this to mean
that the colour scheme simply doesn't support the new setting of `'background'`.
Since the user has indicated they *are using* such a background this means that
the current colour scheme is no longer appropriate, and so Vim unsets
`g:colors_name` and then reloads the default colours.

If you'd like to explore the actual code that is run when `'background'` is set, [you can start here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9652249a2d02318a28a63a7b5711f25652e8f969/src/optionstr.c#L871).

### What's happening in your installation

The odd behaviour you describe (in the first version of your question) can be
explained by this line in the documentation quoted above:

> When a color scheme is loaded *(the "g:colors_name" variable is set)*

The problem is that your `colors/darcula.vim` file doesn't set this value, and
so even though the colors changed when you invoked `:color darcula`, *Vim
doesn't consider a colour scheme to currently be loaded.*

Therefore, when you call `:set background=dark` Vim carries out the step in the
"If no colour scheme is currently loaded" section above, and sets the default
colours for a dark background. This explains why `:color` then reports
`default`.

(Note, however, that setting the default colours does *not*, as you might expect,
remove all the colours that had previously been set, and this is why you end up
with the results you see, rather than the colours that are displayed when you
start up Vim in the first place. [There's some discussion of this issue
here](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/colorscheme-switcher/#known_problems). **Edit**: This issue was fixed in [Vim 8.2.1693](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/05eb5b9cae123b138bbd23cc77e50657ece6b4ad).)

In short, your colour scheme is misconfigured: See `:edit $VIMRUNTIME/colors/README.txt` (in particular the section at the bottom) for
more details on this, and on the interaction between `'background'` and colour
schemes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel completely understood when you say it "does not, as you might expect, remove all the colours that had previously been set". I will surely go read the discussions!

Answer (score 7):

The doc at [`:h 'background'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27background%27)
should provide all the information you need:

> When set to "dark", Vim will try to use colors that look good on a
>   dark background.  When set to "light", Vim will try to use colors that
>   look good on a light background.  Any other value is illegal.

Your colorscheme defines 2 groups of colors: the ones used on a light background
and the ones used on a dark background. The `background` option will tell vim
which group of colors defined by your colorscheme should be used.

> Setting this option does not change the background color, it tells Vim
>   what the background color looks like.  For changing the background
>   color, see [`:h :hi-normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3ahi%2dnormal).
>
> When 'background' is set Vim will adjust the default color groups for
>   the new value.  But the colors used for syntax highlighting will not
>   change.

That's the follow up of the previous paragraph: It's the colorscheme which
defines the groups of colors and `background` selects one of these groups.

Finally if you want to write your own color scheme without having to put `set background=dark` in your vimrc, remember that a colorscheme is nothing more than a program in vimscript, so nothing stops you from using the command directly in the code of your colorscheme like e.g. [jellybeans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim/blob/master/colors/jellybeans.vim#L58) or [apprentice](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice/blob/master/colors/apprentice.vim#L45)

Comment: Thank you! I put `set background=dark` in `darcula.vim` and produced the same effect as when I put it in `.vimrc`. But I'm still curious, how exactly does Vim "try to use colors that look good on a dark background"? Is there a mapping or something like that defined somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Vim is just using you term colors, if you configure something on darkyellow vim will change it to yellow when you change the background mode.

All the colors codes are:

```
*cterm-colors*

NR-16   NR-8    COLOR NAME 
0       0       Black
1       4       DarkBlue
2       2       DarkGreen
3       6       DarkCyan
4       1       DarkRed
5       5       DarkMagenta
6       3       Brown, DarkYellow
7       7       LightGray, LightGrey, Gray, Grey
8       0*      DarkGray, DarkGrey
9       4*      Blue, LightBlue
10      2*      Green, LightGreen
11      6*      Cyan, LightCyan
12      1*      Red, LightRed
13      5*      Magenta, LightMagenta
14      3*      Yellow, LightYellow
15      7*      White
```

If you use an RGB code to configure there will be no change.
So prefer to use a maximum term color.

An example with my .vimrc in dark mode or light mode and my term colors

[image: dark and light]

Answer (score 3):

Setting 'background' adjusts the default colors for the UI highlight groups (`*highlight-groups*`), and resets the standard syntax highlight groups (`*group-name*`) to the default colors for the set background, and thus it must be set before syntax highlighting commands to prevent overriding. If it isn't set explicitly in `.vimrc`, or in a separate colorscheme file loaded at startup, vim sets it itself by querying the background color. The valid values are 'light' and 'dark'.