# NeoVim: colorscheme won't work in init.vim; requires command to be typed

Tags: vimrc, neovim, colorscheme

I'm new to NeoVim and just getting started.
My init.vim file under `NeoVim\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\init.vim` successfully sets everything except for the colorscheme and background.
As seen in the image below, the numbers, color column, etc are all being set correctly, but the colorscheme and background commands are not occurring.

[image]

However, upon typing the commands `:colorscheme default` and `:set background=dark`, everything works fine.
[image]

Here's my init.vim file:

```
let mapleader="`"
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set number
set cursorline
filetype indent on
set wildmenu
set showmatch
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set colorcolumn=80
vmap <C-S-C> "+y
map <C-S-V> "+p
noremap V <C-V>
map <F5> :!j @%
syntax enable
colorscheme default
set background=dark
```

I'm running NVIM v0.3.1 through CMD on Windows 10.
Other than the init.vim file, this is a fresh install.
Is this a known issue with NeoVim?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the Vi & Vim Stack Exchange! Questions about vimrc's and config files should generally include the configuration in question, so those answering have something to go on. Would you mind including your vimrc to help narrow down the issue?

Comment: @ZeroKnight ah yes; the entire vimrc is visible in the pictures, but I'll add it in text form anyway.

Comment: If you use `colorscheme blue` in your init.vim, does it have an effect? I see you're trying to use `colorschme default` at the moment, which doesn't set any colors at all, only leaving them at the *default* colors from your terminal, which depends on your terminal emulator and what colors you have it set to use.

Comment: Also be sure to read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12104/1841) because `set background` might not do exactly what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a `autocmd ColorScheme *` block *after* the `colorscheme` line. This worked in `vim`, but for `nvim` I had to switch it to:

```
autocmd ColorScheme *
        \ highlight constant ctermfg=160 |
        …
        \ highlight special ctermfg=11
colorscheme darkblue
```

I guess in your case it’s the same with `set background=dark`, try putting the `colorscheme` line below it (cf. [What does :set background=dark do?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12104/15871))