# Solve cursor invisible on some highlights

Tags: colorscheme

[image: Screenshot of my Vim]

As you can see in my case, I can barely see my cursor when it is on an error highlighted by You Complete Me as an error. How do I make my cursor more visible?

My GTK+ theme is Numix, I use Gnome and this is the Gnome Terminal in XTerm colors, if that helps.

Comment: what is your background setting?

Comment: Use colors from the background theme, which is Numix, and I don't think that's relevant but I use Arc-Dark as shell theme.

Comment: No, I want to know your background setting. `:set background?`

Comment: Sorry for being so late @ChristianBrabandt, it's light. `background=light`

Comment: So try `:set background=dark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed my problem, was setting background option to dark, as @ChristianBrabandt suggested in comments on my original post. `:set background=dark`

What it basically does is adjusting the background colors without changing the syntax highlighting colors. I won't go into much detail, as [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13089/19752) explains it way better than I ever could.