# Trouble with persistence of background setting via vimrc

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, background

I have a structure thus:

```
myproject/
    .vim/
    .vimrc
```

Contents of `.vimrc` are:

```
let g:usercolour = 0

if g:usercolour == 0
 set background=dark
 colorscheme default
endif
if g:usercolour == 1
 set background=light
 colorscheme desert
endif

"""""""Save Session Info""""""

function! MakeSession()
        exe "mksession! .vim/sessionub.vim"
endfunction

function! LoadSession()
      if (filereadable(".vim/sessionub.vim"))
        exe 'source .vim/sessionub.vim'
      else
        echo "No session loaded."
      endif
endfunction

if(argc() == 0)
    " Adding automatons for when entering or leaving Vim
    au VimEnter * nested :call LoadSession()
    au VimLeave * :call MakeSession()
endif

"""""End Save Session Info""""""""""
```

Essentially, I want to set `g:usercolour=0` for a dark background and `g:usercolour=1` for a light background. When I start vim with this `.vimrc` in my project folder (the .vimrc in the home directory is set to `set exrc` and `set secure` so that the project specific `.vimrc` is loaded), the background is set to `light` and not `dark` as I would have expected.

Is there a way to have vim correctly conditionally set the right background?

Image of the above linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C07gv.jpg), reproduced below:

[image]

---

ETA1: As suggested, I tried flipping the lines thus:

```
if g:usercolour == 0
 set background=dark
 colorscheme default
endif
```

With the above, and everything else same as before, the case of `usercolour=1` does not work. See image of that case [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y1Lo.jpg), reproduced below:

[image]

---

ETA2: As suggested, for `desert` colorscheme too, I set the background to light `after` setting the colorscheme. This does not resolve the issue either. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTyyZ.jpg) reproduced below:

[image]

Essentially, in this case, when I set `g:usercolour = 1` the colorscheme continues to be default and the background dark. So, this if condition is never entered into.

---

ETA3: I tried to remove the parts of the vimrc that save and reload sessions. The situation even now continues to be quite confusing. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMuEj.jpg), reproduced below:

[image]

There are 3 stages in the image, one after the other. (The image is around 80 seconds long)

Stage 1 (first 25 or so seconds): with setting at 1, I save and close .vimrc. Then, I reenter vim. Colorscheme is default, but background is light. This should NOT be.

Stage 2 (next 25 seconds in the gif): Then, I make setting 0 in .vimrc. Save and exit. Then, I reenter vim. Colorscheme is default, and background is dark. This is correct.

Stage 3 (50 seconds until end of gif): Then, I make the setting 1 again, save and close .vimrc. Then, I reenter vim. Colorscheme is default, but background is light. This should NOT be.

---

ETA4: At the gentle and useful prodding of Maxim Kim, I figured out that the desert color scheme is not compatible with a light background! [This](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12104/what-does-set-background-dark-do) link helped in my understanding. Hence, the above seemingly annoying discrepancies. It is resolved now!

Comment: what is your end goal? Do you know what `background` option means/does in vim?

Comment: I tried different colorschemes with set background = light for some, and dark for others, and only some of these combinations worked for me. So, I wanted to set a listing of these pairs in the .vimrc so that I can choose the ones that suited me. However, it is clear that I do not understand what set background does. It seems quite complicated https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12104/what-does-set-background-dark-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `colorscheme default` it resets `background` to default value which is in your case incorrectly detected to be `light`.

So I think if you change the order of commands to:

```
if g:usercolour == 0
 colorscheme default
 set background=dark
...
```

Then it should work for you.

Comment: The suggestion you have work in case usercolour == 0. When I set usercolor=1, the desert scheme is chosen but background persists to be dark and not light. Please see edit to my OP.

Comment: `desert` colorscheme sets `background` as `dark`, so your change before it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Ah. Is there a way to figure out which colorschemes change backgrounds? The reason why I ask is, I have papercolor theme also : https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme and according to this, atleast for this plugin, one should set the background before setting the colorscheme. See specific link https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme#-configure--vimrc

Comment: @Tryer depends on colorscheme implementation, probably by looking into the source of colorscheme

Comment: The situation is even more complicated it seems. Please see ETA2 above. Essentially, when I change the setting from 0 to 1, for some otherworldly reason, the if condition corresponding to 1 is never entered into. I wonder if my saving the sessions info below has anything to do with it. Let me try removing those and see what is going on!